# Ordered/Prioritized return of a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following group of possible values that can appear in a field of a DataFrame (extract from a database):

(N2|N1|N11|N12|N3|N4|N6|N10|N13|N5|N7|N8|N9)

The field can contain any of the above in any combination, for example:

"N1, N6, N9"

I want to extract from every element of the field **only** the one with highest "rank" meaning N9>N8>N7>N5... according to the order of my group above.

So from the example it would return "N9". For "N1, N3, N11" it would return "N3".

Is this possible with RegEx? I am using Python/Pandas on this.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a dataframe `df` with your column of data named `data`, here is a simple way without using regex. Split the strings into columns, then sort the resulting list and take the first element:

```
df.data.str.split(',').apply(lambda l: sorted(l, reverse=True)[0])
Out[7]: 
0    N9
1    N3
Name: data, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick answer. I think this would not work for cases where for example N13 and N9 appear:

Comment: why? N9 > N13 the same way N3 > N11 in your example